# How to make UpdateTargetId work in Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery

I have this method in the controller

```
[HttpDelete]
public void DeleteDocument(int id)
{
   //Here I do the deletion in the db
}
```

In the view I have this, calling a method that returns a partial view

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetDocumentsByMember"); }
```

The GetDocumentsByMember method

```
    public ActionResult GetDocumentsByMember()
    {
        var companyGuid = HttpContextHelper.GetUserCompanyGuid();

        var documents = _service.GetUploadedDocumentsByMember(companyGuid);

        return PartialView(documents);
    }
```

And the partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<GradientCapital.DomainModel.Entity.Document.Document>
<div id="uploadeddocuments">
    @*Here there's a table and at one of the columns there's the next link*@

    <td id="delete">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDocument", new { id = document.Id },
        new AjaxOptions
            {
               Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete?",
               HttpMethod = "DELETE",
               OnComplete = "deleteComplete"
            })
    </td>
</div>
```

And deleteComplete just refresh everything

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteComplete() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Quite long (is correctly formatted?) code for a simple question, I can't make the ajaxoption UpdateTargetId work here instead of having to call this deleteComplete function. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which element do you want to update?

Comment: <div id="uploadeddocuments"> in the partial view

Comment: It looks like you have multiple elements with the same id which obviously results in invalid HTML. Which element do you want to update if you have many `<div id="uploadeddocuments">` in your markup?

Comment: Well the div "uploadeddocuments" just holds the whole table, which is the one I'd like to refres, thing is that I guess I should call again the GetDocumentsByMember and use this UpdateTargetId, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reloading the entire page you could call the `GetDocumentsByMember` action using AJAX and update only the portion of the DOM that has actually changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteComplete() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDocumentsByMember")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#uploadeddocuments').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Also you'd better use `OnSuccess = "deleteSuccess"` instead of `OnComplete = "deleteComplete"` because you should update only if the Delete call actually succeeded. Don't forget that the `OnComplete` callback is always invoked, no matter whether the AJAX call succeeded or not.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the way although debugging the deleteComplete(now deleteSuccess) it doesn't enter in the success: function(result).... even using url: '@Url.Action("GetDocumentsByMember", "UsersDocuments")'

Comment: Have your Delete action return an `ActionResult`, not `void`.

Comment: My fault, I tried to put the deleteComplete/deleteSuccess in a .js file and as far as I found now Url.Action doesn't work there. Inside the view itself works perfectly fine, thanks a lot

Comment: Oh I see. You could use the following approach. Use HTML5 data-* attributes: `<div id="uploadeddocuments" data-url="@Url.Action("GetDocumentsByMember")">` and then inside your external javascript file you could read this value: `url: $('#uploadeddocuments').data('url')`. This way you don't need to be hardcoding the url to the controller action. It will be generated by a helper.