# @Url.Action inside $.get

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen a few posts about this but stills couldn't understand why this is not working

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Edit","Contacts")', {id: parseInt($(this).attr('id')) } , function (result) {
```

obviously this does

```
$.get("/Contacts/Edit/" + parseInt($(this).attr('id')), function (result) {
```

I've tried with replacements and still getting the proper id but the @Url.Actions appears as a string itself generating weird routes as this one for the former code, seems to me that the url.action is not executed, right?

localhost:53720/@Url.Action(Edit,%20Contacts)?id=23918

Edition: Actually the route generated for that code is

localhost:53720/Url.Action(%22Edit%22,%20%22Contacts%22)?id=23918

the other is for another try I've made

Anyone can tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in a JS file or in the HTML file ?

Comment: Try this - `$.get("@Url.Action('Edit','Contacts')"`

Comment: Good question, Aviatrix as you see below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have access to HtmlHelpers inside javascript, the javascript code must be inside a View page, and not inside a javascript file

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("Edit","Contacts")';
    console.log(url);
</script>
```

Comment: Ouch, I definitely should have known that, I'm ashamed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548701/ho-to-make-updatetargetid-work-in-ajax-actionlink Look the last comments

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@Url.Action` is not getting called and the `URL` is not being returned.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Edit","Contacts")';

$.get(url, {id: parseInt($(this).attr('id')) } , function (result)
```

If JS complains about the above, you can try specifying `@:` beforehand to let `razor` take control.